# Math method symbols not found

Tags: java, math, methods

I am following a book on java currently and I try to run this code and am getting a symbol not found error in all the math methods, I though Math was included in the standard java library.

```
public class Math{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double root = Math.sqrt(17.0);
        double angle = 1.5;
        double height = Math.sin(angle);

        double radians = Math.toRadians(180);
        double degrees = Math.toDegrees(Math.PI);
        long round = Math.round(Math.PI * 30);

        System.out.println("Root: " + root);
        System.out.println("Angle: " + angle);
        System.out.println("Height: " + height);
        System.out.println("Radians: " + radians);
        System.out.println("Degrees: " + degrees);
        System.out.println("Round: " + round);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename your class or use the fully qualified name for the java `Math` class

Answer (score 4):

But look, you have just overriden/shadowing it

```
public class Math{
```

It is very bad practice to to this, but if you really want to do this try

```
java.lang.Math.sqrt(...)
```

Comment: So using Math as my java class name is not permit-able?

Comment: I'd describe it as "shadow" rather than override (which comes with method override connocations). But yeah, that's the problem.

Comment: @MattBall You are right, even when I wrote `overriden` I was thinking it was not correct (still have not had enough coffee)

Comment: @dd-beanz - it's permitted, but not recommended, since it leads to confusing behaviour like this. Best practice is to not create classes with the same name as standard Java library classes.

Comment: Thank you all! I did that and it fixed it